# Text based auto generation mail merge

Tags: csv, text-editors, text-formatting, mail-merge

I have a text file.

I would like a simple portable app if possible which can automatically generate 176 different versions where the only difference (e.g. {%FIELD1%} is pulled from a separate file where each pulls from a newline.

I have seen this but this is a word addon which isn't quite what I'm looking for
https://www.gmayor.com/individual_merge_letters.htm

Comment: How portable should it be? Across different OS'es? If not, a bash or powershell script could work.

Comment: I was thinking of a portable Windows application runnable off a usb and only writing to local directory. Powershell script would work a treat if you have any guidance on how to do this?

Comment: Added a script as an example. Note that there [are existing scripts as well](https://www.google.com/search?q=mail+merge+powershell+script) that might be of more use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This script below:

- Loads a text file
- Loads a separate file that contains a list
- Replaces the term `{%FIELD1%}` in the text file by the values in the list
- For every replacement writes out a separate text file

Usage instructions:

- Copy paste below code to a file with a `ps1` extension.
- Open it with Windows PowerShell ISE (or a text editor) and edit the `$mainfile`, `$mergelistfile`, `$fieldstring` and `$outpath` as needed.
- Run the `.ps1` file.

```
# A very simple "mail-merge" script that replaces text in a template file with a 
# value from a list and then writes the text with the replacement to another file.
# This script assumes the following:
# - a $mainfile exists: this is the text file where you want to do the replacements in
# - a $mergelist exists: this is a list of values which you want to use as replacements
# - $mainfile uses the value $fieldstring to indicate the part that should be replaced
# - There either is a writable $outpath or you have permission to create one

$mainfile = '.\mainmerge.txt'
$mergelistfile = '.\mergelist.csv'
$fieldstring = '{%FIELD1%}'
$outpath = '.\mergeoutput'

# Get the mainfile and mergelistfile contents
$maincontent = Get-Content -Path $mainfile -Raw
$mergelist = Get-Content -Path $mergelistfile

# Create the output directory if it doesn't exist yet
if(-Not (Test-Path $outpath)){
    New-Item -ItemType directory -Path $outpath
}

# Loop through $mergelist
$counter = 1
foreach($entry in $mergelist){
    # The output filename with a zero padded number prepended 
    $outfilename = ([string]$counter).PadLeft(3,'0') + " merged.txt"

    # Replace the $fieldstring by the current entry from the mergelist
    $merged = $maincontent -replace $fieldstring, $entry

    # Create the full path of the output file
    $fulloutpath = Join-Path -Path $outpath -ChildPath $outfilename

    # Write the merged file to the full outputpath
    $merged | Add-Content -Path $fulloutpath

    # Increment the counter for the output filename
    $counter++
}
```

Comment: Perfect, simple easy thank you